# When Add a new mapping among Tables in DB,It gives Error: Injection of autowired dependencies failed

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I am using Spring mvc and hibernate.i have successfully mapping table one to many..but now i want to mapping existing table those are already mapping another with tables..but i want to map it with another table..when i do it..it gives below error

MODEL

```
package pearson.dashboard.model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Meetings {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int meetingID;
    @Column
    private Date sheduleTime;
    @Column
    private String meetingHeading;
    @Column 
    private String comment;
    @Column
    private String roomName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "meetingTypeID") 
    private MeetingTypes meetingTypes;



    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "releaseID") 
    private Releases releases;


    public Releases getReleases() {
        return releases;
    }

    public void setReleases(Releases releases) {
        this.releases = releases;
    }

    public MeetingTypes getMeetingTypes() {
        return meetingTypes;
    }

    public void setMeetingTypes(MeetingTypes meetingTypes) {
        this.meetingTypes = meetingTypes;
    }

    public Meetings() {

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Meetings(int meetingID, Date sheduleTime, String meetingHeading,
            String comment, String roomName) {
        super();
        this.meetingID = meetingID;
        this.sheduleTime = sheduleTime;
        this.meetingHeading = meetingHeading;
        this.comment = comment;
        this.roomName = roomName;

    }

    public int getMeetingID() {
        return meetingID;
    }

    public void setMeetingID(int meetingID) {
        this.meetingID = meetingID;
    }

    public Date getSheduleTime() {
        return sheduleTime;
    }

    public void setSheduleTime(Date sheduleTime) {
        this.sheduleTime = sheduleTime;
    }

    public String getMeetingHeading() {
        return meetingHeading;
    }

    public void setMeetingHeading(String meetingHeading) {
        this.meetingHeading = meetingHeading;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public String getRoomName() {
        return roomName;
    }

    public void setRoomName(String roomName) {
        this.roomName = roomName;
    }
}
```

#

```
package pearson.dashboard.model;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Releases {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) 
    private int releaseID;  
    @Column
    private String orcleCode;
    @Column
    private String status;
    @Column
    private Date staging;
    @Column
    private Date cabCall;
    @Column 
    private Date rrr;
    @Column
    private String remarks;
    @Column
    private String releaseName;
    @Column 
    private Date prodDate;  

    @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "teamID")
    private Teams teams;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "meetings",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Meetings> meetings;        

    public List<Meetings> getMeetings() {
        return meetings;
    }
    public void setMeetings(List<Meetings> meetings) {
        this.meetings = meetings;
    }

    public Teams getTeams() {
        return teams;
    }
    public void setTeams(Teams teams) {
        this.teams = teams;
    }
    public Releases() {}
    public Releases(int releasID, String orcleCode, String status,
            Date staging, Date cabCall, Date rrr, String remarks,
            String releaseName,Date prodDate) {
        super();
        this.releaseID = releasID;
        this.orcleCode = orcleCode;
        this.status = status;
        this.staging = staging;
        this.cabCall = cabCall;
        this.rrr = rrr;
        this.remarks = remarks;
        this.releaseName = releaseName;
        this.prodDate = prodDate;
    }

    public int getReleaseID() {
        return releaseID;
    }
    public void setReleaseID(int releaseID) {
        this.releaseID = releaseID;
    }

    public String getOrcleCode() {
        return orcleCode;
    }
    public void setOrcleCode(String orcleCode) {
        this.orcleCode = orcleCode;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public Date getStaging() {
        return staging;
    }
    public void setStaging(Date staging) {
        this.staging = staging;
    }
    public Date getCabCall() {
        return cabCall;
    }
    public void setCabCall(Date cabCall) {
        this.cabCall = cabCall;
    }
    public Date getRrr() {
        return rrr;
    }
    public void setRrr(Date rrr) {
        this.rrr = rrr;
    }
    public String getRemarks() {
        return remarks;
    }
    public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
        this.remarks = remarks;
    }
    public String getReleaseName() {
        return releaseName;
    }
    public void setReleaseName(String releaseName) {
        this.releaseName = releaseName;
    }
    public Date getProdDate() {
            return prodDate;
        }
    public void setProdDate(Date prodDate) {
            this.prodDate = prodDate;
        }                   
}
```

#### Controller

```
package pearson.dashboard.controller;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import pearson.dashboard.dto.NewMeeting;
import pearson.dashboard.model.MeetingTypes;
import pearson.dashboard.model.Meetings;
import pearson.dashboard.service.MeetingService;
import pearson.dashboard.service.MeetingTypeService;

@Controller
public class MeetingController {

    @Autowired
    private MeetingService meetingService;  

    @RequestMapping(value="/addNewMeeting",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addMeeting(@ModelAttribute NewMeeting newMeeting,BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> map){
        String typeName           = newMeeting.getTypeName();
        MeetingTypes meetingTypes = meetingService.getMeetingTypeByName(typeName); 

        Meetings meetings = new Meetings();
        meetings.setMeetingTypes(meetingTypes);
        meetings.setRoomName(newMeeting.getRoomName());
        meetings.setComment(newMeeting.getComment());
        meetings.setSheduleTime(newMeeting.getSheduleTime());
        meetingService.add(meetings);

        return "redirect:/detailsPage";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/editMeeting",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editMeetingMethod(@ModelAttribute NewMeeting newMeeting,BindingResult result,Map<String, Object> map){
        int meetingID = newMeeting.getMeetingID();
        Meetings meetings = meetingService.getMeetingByMeetingID(meetingID);
        meetings.setMeetingID(meetingID);
        meetings.setRoomName(newMeeting.getTypeName());
        meetings.setRoomName(newMeeting.getRoomName());
        meetings.setComment(newMeeting.getComment());
        if(newMeeting.getSheduleTime()==null){

        }
        else{
            meetings.setSheduleTime(newMeeting.getSheduleTime());
        }
        meetingService.update(meetings);
        return "redirect:/detailsPage";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/deleteMeeting", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String deleteMeetingMethod(@ModelAttribute NewMeeting newMeeting,BindingResult result,Map<String, Object> map){
        Meetings meetings = new Meetings();
        meetings.setMeetingID(newMeeting.getMeetingID());
        meetingService.delete(meetings);


        return "redirect:/detailsPage";
    }

}
```

## servlet Context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="pearson.dashboard" />


    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="configLocation">
            <beans:value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="configurationClass">
            <beans:value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</beans:value>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
 <tx:annotation-driven />
    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>


</beans:beans>
```

##### Part of Error

```
Dec 03, 2013 4:06:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\jre\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Perforce;C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN\bin;.
Dec 03, 2013 4:06:52 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:PearsonProjectDashboard' did not find a matching property.
Dec 03, 2013 4:06:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 03, 2013 4:06:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 03, 2013 4:06:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1675 ms
Dec 03, 2013 4:06:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 03, 2013 4:06:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.33
Dec 03, 2013 4:06:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Dec 03, 2013 4:06:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Dec 03, 2013 4:06:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
Dec 03, 2013 4:07:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'meetingController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private pearson.dashboard.service.MeetingService pearson.dashboard.controller.MeetingController.meetingService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'meetingServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: pearson.dashboard.dao.MeetingDao pearson.dashboard.service.impl.MeetingServiceImpl.meetingDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'meetingDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory pearson.dashboard.dao.impl.MeetingDaoImpl.session; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on pearson.dashboard.model.Releases.meetings references an unknown entity: java.util.List
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private pearson.dashboard.service.MeetingService pearson.dashboard.controller.MeetingController.meetingService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'meetingServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: pearson.dashboard.dao.MeetingDao pearson.dashboard.service.impl.MeetingServiceImpl.meetingDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'meetingDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory pearson.dashboard.dao.impl.MeetingDaoImpl.session; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on pearson.dashboard.model.Releases.meetings references an unknown entity: java.util.List
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'meetingServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: pearson.dashboard.dao.MeetingDao pearson.dashboard.service.impl.MeetingServiceImpl.meetingDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'meetingDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory pearson.dashboard.dao.impl.MeetingDaoImpl.session; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on pearson.dashboard.model.Releases.meetings references an unknown entity: java.util.List
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: pearson.dashboard.dao.MeetingDao pearson.dashboard.service.impl.MeetingServiceImpl.meetingDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'meetingDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory pearson.dashboard.dao.impl.MeetingDaoImpl.session; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on pearson.dashboard.model.Releases.meetings references an unknown entity: java.util.List
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'meetingDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory pearson.dashboard.dao.impl.MeetingDaoImpl.session; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on pearson.dashboard.model.Releases.meetings references an unknown entity: java.util.List
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory pearson.dashboard.dao.impl.MeetingDaoImpl.session; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on pearson.dashboard.model.Releases.meetings references an unknown entity: java.util.List
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at
```

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question currently it is quite unclear what you are asking...

Comment: I have many tables those a mapped and working properly..now i want to one to many mapping again with existing tables..so i fallowed previous strategy then it gives bellow Error..thanks i am little bit new

Comment: Instead of a comment please update your question. Describe what you want cleary and describe the problem. Currently it is all a bit vague (initially I figured you want multiple classes to map to the same table). You don't want any confusion in what you ask/request.

Comment: YES>>>multiple classes to map to the same table

Comment: Actually that is not what you want (you don't want a class x1 and x2 to map to table Z). You just want a many-to-one mapping in one of your classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the actuall cause of the exception..

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on pearson.dashboard.model.Releases.meetings references an unknown entity: java.util.List
```

Your mapping is wrong

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "meetings",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Meetings> meetings;
```

Your `mappedBy` attribute should reference a property inside the `Meetings` object. I highly doubt that your `Meetings` object has a `meetings` property. Judging from the code the `mappedBy` attribute should refer to the 'releases' property.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "releases",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Meetings> meetings;
```

Probably a sloppy-paste error. You might want to read up on JPA and how mappings work instead of blindly copying something that might work. Understanding is the key here.

Comment: Thanks ..it was one Erro in that..and i change to list TO set ..now it i s working